# Using jQuery to close lightbox div from a button

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below code is there a function that would enable me to closing a lightbox div `.productInformation` within my confirm function?

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('body').on("click", "#product_delete_product", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var box = $("#product_delete_product");
    var id = box.data("id");
    var name = box.data("name");

    var url = box.data("url");
    var data_array = {
        id: id,
    };

    if (confirm("Delete " + name + "?")) {
        ajaxCall(url, data_array, null, 'product_delete');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I was using colorbox I solved my issue buy adding the following:

`$(this).colorbox.close();`

Answer (score 1):

If by closing you mean setting display:none, you can use

```
box.hide()
```